# Returning predictions when comparing data frames

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the following two data frames:

```
df1 = {
    'file_names': ['file_name1', 'file_name2', 'file_name3', 'file_name4'],
    'class1': [0.655, 0.5216, 0.1561, 0.5616],
    'class2': [0.5216, 0.0231, 0.516, 0.546],
    'class3': [0.2131, 0.516, 0.2165, 0.651],
    'class4': [0.65, 0.2165, 0.2165, 0.05616],
    'class5': [0.01265, 0.0516, 0.05, 0.0561]
}
```

and

```
df2 = {
    'class': ['class2', 'class3', 'class4', 'class1', 'class5'],
    'threshold': [0.2165, 0.5165, 0.79874, 0.216, 0.3546]
}
```

I am trying to return an output such that when looking at the columns in df1 that match a class in df2 and the associated threshold is greater than or equal to the value found in df1 then I get an output such as:

| file_name | predictions |
| --- | --- |
| file_name1 | class2, class4 |

I have tried the following:

```
df2 = df2.set_index('class')['threshold'].to_dict()


def get_predictions(row):
    predictions = []
    for col in df1.columns[1:]:
        if row[col] >= threshold_dict.get(col, 0):
            predictions.append(col)
    return ', '.join(predictions)

df1['prediction'] = df1.apply(get_predictions, axis=1)
```

But i get an error stating: 'class1'. Without any other info in JupyterNotebook. Why may this be?

So then I tried iterrows thinking that instead of trying to compare via columns just going through each row instead:

```
results = []

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    file_name = row['file_name']
    prediction = []
    
    # Iterate over columns of df1(classes)
    for column in adf1.columns[1:]:
        if row[column] >= df2[column].values[0]:
            prediction.append(column)
    
    results.append({'file_name': file_name, 'prediction': ', '.join(prediction)})
```

But this returns an error of "Index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0" which tells me something is going wrong to not grab the column names.

What Can I do to get the output for all file_names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'file_names': ['file_name1', 'file_name2', 'file_name3', 'file_name4'],
    'class1': [0.655, 0.5216, 0.1561, 0.5616],
    'class2': [0.5216, 0.0231, 0.516, 0.546],
    'class3': [0.2131, 0.516, 0.2165, 0.651],
    'class4': [0.65, 0.2165, 0.2165, 0.05616],
    'class5': [0.01265, 0.0516, 0.05, 0.0561]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'class': ['class2', 'class3', 'class4', 'class1', 'class5'],
    'threshold': [0.2165, 0.5165, 0.79874, 0.216, 0.3546]
})

output = {'file_name': [], 'predictions': []}

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    predictions = []
    for col in df1.columns[1:]:  # excluding the 'file_names' column
        if col in df2['class'].values:
            threshold = df2.loc[df2['class'] == col, 'threshold'].iloc[0]
            if row[col] >= threshold:
                predictions.append(col)
output['file_name'].append(row['file_names'])
output['predictions'].append(', '.join(predictions))

output_df = pd.DataFrame(output)
print(output_df)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This kind of works on my end. When I execute your code I seem to only output the first row as opposed to all four. I double checked the shape of my dataframes and they remain unchanged so not sure why this would happen?

Comment: I realized it was an indentation error on my end when appended output. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) df1 on `file_names` and then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) it with `df2` on `class`; select all the rows where the threshold is exceeded and then use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to aggregate the `class` values into a list:

```
mm = df1.melt(id_vars='file_names', var_name='class').merge(df2, on='class')
mask = mm['value'] > mm['threshold']
res = mm[mask].groupby('file_names', as_index=False)['class'].agg(list)
```

Output:

```
   file_names                     class
0  file_name1          [class1, class2]
1  file_name2                  [class1]
2  file_name3                  [class2]
3  file_name4  [class1, class2, class3]
```

If you want a comma-separated list of values, just change the aggregate function to `', '.join`:

```
res = mm[mask].groupby('file_names', as_index=False)['class'].agg(', '.join)
```

Output:

```
   file_names                   class
0  file_name1          class1, class2
1  file_name2                  class1
2  file_name3                  class2
3  file_name4  class1, class2, class3
```

You can of course do this all in one statement using [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) if that is helpful:

```
res = (df1
    .melt(id_vars='file_names', var_name='class')
    .merge(df2, on='class')
    .pipe(lambda x:x[x['value'] > x['threshold']])
    .groupby('file_names', as_index=False)['class']
    .agg(', '.join)
)
```